# One word for a person who loves his things?

Tags: single-word-requests

One word for a person who loves his things? Take for example if a person loves his car or a pen or things like these.

Comment: Are you asking about a person who loves a specific thing (such as his car **or** his pen) or a person who loves things in general (loves his car **and** his pen and his fruit bowl and his guitar...)  Also, when you say _love_, do you mean "_Like or enjoy very much_" as in "I love a good lengua burrito" or "_Feel deep affection or sexual love for_" as in "I love my wife"?  I read an article about a woman who supposedly claimed she was married to a train station, so the last bit is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the best answer would be: ***materialist***. This is sense 2 of the OED entry on *materialist* - as follows, with examples.

> 2. A person who favours material possessions and physical comfort over spiritual things; a person who adopts a materialistic way of life.
>
> 1853   E. Bulwer-Lytton My Novel II. vii. vi. 214   ‘O materialist!’
>   cried the boy..‘you would debase the gods to a gin-palace.’
>
> 1856   R. W. Emerson Eng. Traits xiv. 233   He [sc. the Englishman]
>   loves the axe, the spade, the oar, the gun... He is materialist,
>   economical, mercantile.
>
> 1959   J. W. Krutch Human Nature & Human Condition i. 6   But we are
>   materialists..in the very simple sense that we believe everything
>   worth having can be had if we are willing to spend enough money to get
>   it.
>
> 1979   P. Mortimer About Time ii. 25   My mother's family, stern
>   materialists who believed devoutly in success, refused to have
>   anything to do with him.
>
> 1987   Amer. Polit. Sci. Rev. 81 1305/1   Materialists are those who
>   place a high priority on a stable economy, economic growth, fighting
>   rising prices and..on securing a high-paying job, adequate housing,
>   and a comfortable life.